# AuthorizationPolicy set status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an `AuthorizationHandler` and I would like to return a custom statuscode ( or text ) right now I am just trying to make it return 429 ( which is for rate limit but that's not relevant )

```
public class ReCaptchaHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ReCaptchaRequirement>
{
    private readonly ReCaptcha _reCaptcha;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public ReCaptchaHandler(ReCaptcha reCaptcha, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _reCaptcha = reCaptcha;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
    protected override  Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        ReCaptchaRequirement requirement)
    {

        context.Fail();
        _accessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class ReCaptchaRequirement :  IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

as you can see, I am trying to set the status = 429 with `_accessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;`

I have tried using the http context from `var filterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;` and then `filterContext.HttpContext`

I create my policy as follows

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ReCaptchaHandler>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ReCaptcha",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ReCaptchaRequirement()));
});
```

The code runs and protects the route marked with `[Authorize(Policy = "ReCaptcha")]` but the status is always 400 unless I throw an exception.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you set the `StatusCode` as follows it works

```
context.Fail();
var Response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
var message= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ReCaptcha failed");
Response.OnStarting(async () =>
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);
});
```

Comment: Thank You SO Much. You saved me finally.

Comment: Thanks you this works for me , with a minor change for filterContext to be like:
var filterContext= context.Resource as DefaultHttpContext;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to override the exception code for an API call, If so, have you tried adding a new exception filter to MVC configuration filter and then override the status code on exception, something like this.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(someExceptionFilter));
            })


public class someExceptionFilter: IExceptionFilter
    {
        public someExceptionFilter()
        {

        }
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var exceptionType = context.Exception.GetType();
            if (exceptionType == typeof(yourException))
            {
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

                response.StatusCode = 429;
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
                //response.WriteAsync(context.Exception.Message);
                context.Result = new JsonResult(context.Exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can see how this would work, but I would rather not have to throw an exception from my `Handler` .  Let see if anything else comes in.  -- thanks

Comment: when the error is raised from `HandleRequirementAsync` the global event filter does not fire.